# Google Sheets Is Outputting as CSV in Postman. How can I output as JSON?

Tags: json, api, csv, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I've tried using `?alt=json` instead of `&output=csv`, but I'm not having luck. Is it possible to output this Google Sheet as a JSON file?

The 2nd URL is returning the csv data in Postman, but issues trying to get JSON data returned.

**The Google Sheets URL:**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS6HT4AanTSghUQZr_YWAauahN_zv6mhPcRMeAV8mGpTBs4ZixA09cqPMnZMCrivRbeU2FQ1RdiOMmo/pub?gid=0&single=true

**The Google Sheets URL (CSV Output):**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS6HT4AanTSghUQZr_YWAauahN_zv6mhPcRMeAV8mGpTBs4ZixA09cqPMnZMCrivRbeU2FQ1RdiOMmo/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv

Comment: In your case, the Spreadsheet ID can be used instead of `2PACX-###`?

Comment: Where do I find the spreadsheet ID? Is it 1vS6HT4AanTSghUQZr_YWAauahN_zv6mhPcRMeAV8mGpTBs4ZixA09cqPMnZMCrivRbeU2FQ1RdiOMmo/pub?gid=0&single=true

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. `2PACX-###` is different from the Spreadsheet ID. I asked whether you know the Spreadsheet ID.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/spreadsheetID/od6/public/values?alt=json
```

where you supply the **spreadsheetID** with:

[image: 0]

https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample

Comment: The ID from the URL https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS6HT4AanTSghUQZr_YWAauahN_zv6mhPcRMeAV8mGpTBs4ZixA09cqPMnZMCrivRbeU2FQ1RdiOMmo/pub?gid=0 doesn't seem to work when switched out

Comment: https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1vS6HT4AanTSghUQZr_YWAauahN_zv6mhPcRMeAV8mGpTBs4ZixA09cqPMnZMCrivRbeU2FQ1RdiOMmo/od6/public/values?alt=json doesn't work

Comment: Is it possible due to that there are 2 tabs?

Comment: Hi ! That might be the issue although I doubt that is the main reason why this is failing. Could you try to make sure this wasnt the issue the following?: ```https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/spreadsheetID/gid=0/od6/public/values?alt=json```